# Not able to pass JOB PARAMETER to Steps - Spring BatchJobs

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We are implementing Spring Batch Jobs,

We need to pass the job parameter from Client/MASTER to SLAVE.
CLIENT/MASTER is where our Job and partitioning code is present. We are calling the JOB using J Unit passing the JOB PARAMETER.

SLAVE is where all the Steps and its implementation(reader Writer and processor) is defined.

We are able to achieve this in a standalone way, but not with Client  & SERVER way. I am not sure why we are not able to achieve our set up, where we are able to achieve in Standalone?

We are using Weblogic and Spring Integration along with JMS to Achieve the same

Please assist.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to ask. What do you mean by "not able to achieve"? what is Client/MASTER SLAVE that you are talking about?

Comment: CLIENT is where all our JOB and partition related code is present. For Example: in a Batch Jobs - Code related to Job and Partitioning is in the Client side - Meaning We will have only one Master and Multiple Slaves (Where all our Steps -  Reader, Processor and Writer are configured on multiple instances)                                                                    We have used JMS implementation - MASTER and SLAVE

Comment: We are able to  achieve this and same code is placed below:'<bean id="feedProcedureCall"
  class="com.kohls.batch.integrations.endeca.KLSFeedProcedureCall"
  scope="step">
  <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jTemplate"></property>
  <property name="load" value="#{jobParameters[load]}"></property>
 </bean>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to resolve this issue as below in our bean configuration file:

```
<property name="load" value="#{jobParameters[load]}"></property>
```

load is passed from our Shell script

**./esk200.sh esk200-context.xml TIMESTAMP load=full**